# Migrating a decimal column to default 0 becomes negative in the schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I was following the steps described [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns):

For a little background, this web app is for an auction management system. The `amount_raised` column in the `Auction` class is supposed to represent a dollar amount, the amount of money that is made at the auction. By default, I wanted to have it be `$0.00`. My set method in the `auction.rb` file is as follows:

```
def amount_raised=(val)
  currency = val.to_s.gsub(/[-$,]/,'').to_f if val.present?
  write_attribute(:amount_raised, currency)
end
```

The first migration I tried to make is the following:

```
change_column_default :auctions, :amount_raised, from: nil, to: 0.00
```

But, this change resulted in the following in my `schema.rb` file (precision and scale were already there):

```
t.decimal  "amount_raised", precision: 5, scale: 2, default: -0.0
```

I tried to make another migration to change the default from `-0.0` to `nil` (because I figured if I couldn't get 0 to work I could do the proper format in the view by checking for a nil and having it print $0.00) but the default remained at -0.0.

I have attempted to rollback the migrations but they are throwing exceptions as being "irreversible migrations" which is what I was trying to avoid by using `from: nil, to: 0.00` to begin with.

My questions are, having followed the format from the Rails guide, what did I do incorrectly? What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run an empty migration:

```
rails generate migration AddAmountRaisedToAuctions
```

Then inside your `change` method add the below code:

```
def change
  change_column :auctions, :amount_raised, :decimal, :null => false, :default => 0
end
```

Now run rake db:migrate.

Comment: Does it matter that the column already exists? Will this disrupt any data that is already present that have non-nil values?

Comment: Ya if the column already exists instead of `add_column` it will be `change_column`. It won't disrupt the existing data though not sure about that.

Comment: This worked! Any idea why my original method made it unhappy?

Comment: Not sure but something wrong about your `gsub` I guess.